# Stackview calling slots for previous screen

Tags: qt, qml, stackview

I am implementing stackview in my application.

```
SwipeView {
id: swipeView
anchors.fill: parent
currentIndex: showfooter.currentIndex

        DashboardListView{
        id:dashboard
        }

        Settings{
        id:setting
        }

        Cart{
        id:cart
        }
}


StackView {
   id: stackView

   initialItem: Pane {
      id: pane
   }
}
```

When i am loading some other screen(like SightDescription.qml) from DashboardListView using push method and cliking somewhere on that screen its calling slots for DashboardListView. DashboardListView Screen controls are getting onclick signal. Is there any setting related to stack view that I need to do, I read stackview's documentation but did not find anything to restrict this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `Pane` is usually intercepting the mouse events, so the lower `Item`s cannot receive them.

When you push the new item on the `StackView` the `Pane` becomes `visible: false` and therefore does not care for input anymore. If the new `Item` does not handle the mouse events, they will propagate to the lower `Item`.

To prevent that, you have various options:

1. Make sure that all `Item`s pushed on the `StackView` will handle mouse events, e.g. by making a `Pane` or a `MouseArea` the root item.
2. Place a `MouseArea` directly below the `StackView` that is only enabled when there are `Item`s on the `StackView`
3. Some more... e.g. installing `EventFilter`s in C++ e.t.c. but I think 1 and 2 should be suffice and be easy to implement.